# Mock Non-existent Interface in PHP

Tags: php, drupal, mocking, phpunit

I am new to PHP unit testing and I need some clarity on how can we mock non-existent Interface. Basically, In my project, I want to test one protected method which is expecting two arguments one is Interface and another is a string.

I want to understand how can I pass Interface as an argument in a method. I tried to Mock the Interface but it's not working for me.

This is my main class

```
namespace App\Models;

class VerifyNs {
    protected function NsCheck(SomeInterface $url, string $domain) {
        $answer= dns_get_record($domain, DNS_NS);
        if (!empty($answer[0]['target']), ('example.com' == substr($answer[0]['target'], -11)) {
            $result = 'NS verification for @url passed., ['@url ' => $url ->getName()]';
            return $result
        }

        return 'failed;
    }

    
}
```

Here is the test case

```
class VerifyNsTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    /**
     * To call protected method
     * @param $object
     * @param string $method
     * @param array $parameters
     * @return mixed
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    private function callMethod($object, string $method , array $parameters = [])
    {
        try {
            $className = get_class($object);
            $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($className);
        } catch (\ReflectionException $e) {
           throw new \Exception($e->getMessage());
        }

        $method = $reflection->getMethod($method);
        $method->setAccessible(true);

        return $method->invokeArgs($object, $parameters);
    }

    /**
    * Tests for verifying NS of the domain.
    *
    * @dataProvider providerTestNsCheck
    */
    public function testCheckNs($site, $url, $expected_result) {
        $site_name = $this->getMockBuilder(SomeInterface::class)
                          ->setMethods(['getName'])
                          ->getMock();
        
        $site_name->method('getName')->willReturn($site);

        $verifyNs = new \App\Models\VerifyNs();
        $this->assertEquals($expected_result, $this->callMethod($verifyNs, 'NsCheck', [ $site_name, $url]));
    }

    /**
     * Data provider for testCheckNs().
     *
     */
    public function providerTestNsCheck() {
        return [
        [
            'mysite',
            'example.com',
            'NS verification for mysite passed.',
       
        ],       [   
            'google',
            'google.com',
            'failed.'
            ]
        ],
        ];
    }

}
```

After running this, it's giving me an error

`TypeError: Argument 1 passed to App\Models\VerifyNs::NsCheck() must be an instance of App\Models\SomeInterface, instance of Mock_SomeInterface_1ee04960 given`

Can someone please help here? Is it possible to mock non_existent Interface and pass it as an argument to the method?

Comment: What do you mean by "not existent interface"? Does your testcase include a correct use statement for `SomeInterface`?

Comment: Yes, it does. basically the Interface is complicated in another file, So rather creating actual Interface in the test case, I want to mock it and pass it as an argument to the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue using prophesize

$site = $this->prophesize(SomeInterface::class);
$object =$site->reveal()

then passing $object in the callMethod.